# Android - Passing Variables across multiple activities

Tags: java, android

There has to be a cleaner method to passing data / variables between Activities 
At the moment i have 4 Activities (When am finished i may end up with 12 /14

Each of these Activities is communication with a Microsoft Database. Doing various tasks, lookup, Checks, Data Alterations etc
Everything works well, But i am finding each time i am creating an Intent to start a new Activity, I am having to copy and paste loads of  `intent.putExtra()` to pass between each of the Activities. 
It's just looking messy and unneeded.

Is there a better way to do this? From PHP i would wrap all of these in a function and cut out the need to repeat the same code over and over again.

I don't seem to be able to share data between activities without putting in in intent or storing it in shared activity 
(I am new to the Java / Android development, but i am seeing a Activity as a new program opposed to a new page within an application the way its structured and ability to pass / share data)

Comment: why not creating a public static variable and load it content at your first activity and then you can use it as well in the other activities directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should never be doing that directly in the activities.  Use a intent factory pattern.  For example:

```
class MyActivity {
    static Intent createIntent(Context context, param1, param2, param3...) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context);
       intent.setExtra("param1", param1);
       ...
       return intent;
}
```

That way the calling code just needs to call this function, and all the knowledge of extras and their names go away.

Now if there's common data to all of your activities (for example session data), hen other solutions like global variables or injection frameworks may be applicable.  But if its data only needed for that individual activity, it becomes one of the parameters to that createIntent function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class as a singleton in which you store the data you need and then access them from the getInstance of the singleton..A kind of session